# Qt "no matching function for call"

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I have

```
no matching function for call to 'saveLine::saveLine()'
```

error when compiling my application. The construcor is never actually called.

saveLine class definition:

```
class saveLine
{
public:
    saveLine(QWidget *parent);
private:
    QPushButton *selectButton, *acceptButton;
    QLabel *filePath;
    QLineEdit *allias;
};
```

saveLine is used in another class which is defined as follows:

```
class MWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MWindow(QWidget *parent=0);
private:
    saveLine line1;
};
```

error points to MWindow constructor implementation

```
MWindow::MWindow(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setWindowTitle("Launcher");
    this->resize(600,600);
}
```

What should i do? I intend to use saveLine class in a vector, to create lines at runtime.

EDIT: i've misdeclared line1, it should read

```
saveLine *line1;
```

but now it gives another error

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'saveLine' with no type
```

and

```
expected ';' before '*' token
```

on this line. It seems like saveLine is no longer considered a class, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but now it gives another error
>
> ISO C++ forbids declaration of
>   'saveLine' with no type

You need to add a forward declaration to tell the compiler that saveLine class exists:

Like this:

```
//declare that there will be a class saveLine
class saveLine;

class MWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MWindow(QWidget *parent=0);
private:
    saveLine *line1;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you provide a user-declared constructor for the class `saveLine`, the default constructor is not provided by the compiler.  Your constructor is not a default constructor (it has one required parameter), so you cannot default construct an object of type `saveLine`.

Since you have a `saveLine` object in your `MWindow` class, you need to initialize it using your constructor, in the `MWindow` constructor's initializer list:

```
MWindow::MWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), line1(parent)
{
    //...
}
```

(I'm assuming that parent pointer is the one you mean to pass; if you need to give it something else, then give it what it needs)

Another option would be to provide a default argument for the parameter in `saveLine`'s constructor:

```
saveLine(QWidget *parent = 0);
```

This would allow that constructor to be called with no arguments (and would make it a default constructor).  Whether this makes sense to do depends on whether the parent pointer really is optional.  Obviously, if you do this, you'll need to check to be sure the pointer is not null before you dereference and use it.

Comment: Minor nit: You should pass `this` instead of `parent` to `line1()`.

Comment: Good point - allways specify your own default constructor in addition to overloaded constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the constructor of saveLine in the constructor of MWindow giving him the desired parent.

Use:

```
MWindow::MWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), line1(parent)
{
    this->setWindowTitle("Launcher");
    this->resize(600,600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an instance of saveLine in the class declaration, instead of a pointer to a saveLine.

You could change the reference in MWindow to

```
saveLine* line1;
```

OR

you could implement like this:

```
MWindow::MWindow(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent), line1(parent)
{
    this->setWindowTitle("Launcher");
    this->resize(600,600);
}
```

Comment: What is this modded down for?

Comment: I wonder as well, i indeed forgot to use a pointer. Althoug compiler now has different error
"ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'saveLine' with no type" and
"expected ';' before '*' token"

Comment: Perhaps you are missing your #include directive?

Comment: No, it's exactly where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `class saveLine;` just above the `class MWindow` line.  This often occurs when the .h files for the saveLine class and the MWindow class include each other (either directly or indirectly).  For example, see the first few posts of http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/594307